# How to Load LOV into an APEX shuttle

Tags: oracle-apex

APEX rev 20.2

This is my first time using shuttles and I am quite new to APEX. I looked around and haven't been able to  figure out how to load rows from a collection into an APEX shuttle. I tried the following in the List of Values Section using SQL:

```
    select c003 AS d,
    c001 AS r
    from apex_collections where c002 LIKE 'SEL' and collection_name='MEDIACARDS'
```

I have displayed the collection and know there are values in c003 and numbers in c001. Also SEL in c002.

Nothing is displayed in the shuttle.

Any advice I what I am doing wrong or how to trouble shoot the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: 'MEDIACARDS' is a collection - did you populate the collection ?  Are you sure you need a collection ? Note that the ```LIKE 'SEL'``` with no wildcards will only return records where c002 = 'SEL'

Comment: I displayed the collection and see that it is populated and that SEL is in the c002 column. Collections make my task easy to accomplish. Is there a downside to collections?

Comment: I tried the same query with select list and it also is empty, so it looks like I am querying the collection incorrectly.

Comment: any reason you're not selecting from the base table the collection is based on ? Collection is great for temporarily storing data and have several use cases, but in most apps, they're not needed.

Comment: I have a flowchart where each node has details. The collection stored the details temporarily. Then the details are loaded into JSON which then becomes part of the flowchart JSON. The flowchart has undo redo functionality. If I load the details into the flowchart JSON, that functionality is handled automatically.  If I store the node details in a table, I will have to somehow track which rows need to be deleted so I don't have unused rows. Maybe it isn't really a big problem since the unused rows will go away when I delete related all rows for a deleted flowchart. A table would be easier.

Comment: I could have each node point to a pkey in a  NODE_DETAIL table. If the user deletes the node, there would be an unused row, but it would be available in case the user undoes the delete. I will check to see how big the undo stack is for the flowchart. Maybe I can delete the oldest unused rows after a while.

Answer (score 0):

The collection starts out empty, then is filled with values. I thought that by refreshing the region containing the shuttle, the shuttle would also be refreshed. That wasn't true. Once I refreshed the shuttle directly, it loaded the updated collection and all is well.

Comment: You're providing a ton of info in your answer that wasn't in the original question :).

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, but I thought it was that simple at first. After hours of troubleshooting I found additional details.